# Change configuration keyboard / Key not working

Tags: keyboard, 23.10

My key "ç" of my keyboard does not work anymore and I would like to keep this keyboard so I would to configure this key to be active on another key.

French "ç" is at number 9 on English keyboard.

That would be great to be able to push "Fn" + "8" to hit "ç".
Is it possible?

Also on this Logitech K810 french keyboard, the keys < ans ² are alternated, can I fix it?